# Set Y position of Floating Button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button

I am currently using this great floating button library from [GitHub](https://github.com/kciter/Floaty). The only problem I have is it is below the Tab bar. I am trying to update the height of the button but I am not sure which function updates the height of the floating button.

```
open class Floaty: UIView {
    // MARK: - Properties

    /**
        `FloatyItem` objects.
    */
    open var items: [FloatyItem] = []

    /**
        This object's button size.
    */
    open var size: CGFloat = 56 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
            self.recalculateItemsOrigin()
        }
    }

    /**
        Padding from bottom right of UIScreen or superview.
    */
    open var paddingX: CGFloat = 14 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    open var paddingY: CGFloat = 60 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
```

Comment: post some code to try help you

Comment: @ReinierMelian I just updated the Y padding and it is working now!

Comment: ok congrats then

Comment: @ReinierMelian thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Updated Y padding and it moved the y position of the button.